# R adding extra rows in a matrix where row names are unique

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with row names a and e and column names a b c d e.

```
  a b c d e
a 1 0 0 1 0
e 1 0 0 1 0
```

I am trying to create a square matrix with new rows (3 in this case) like this.

```
  a b c d e
a 1 0 0 1 0
e 1 0 0 1 0
b 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0
```

three new rows with names b c & d (unique row names) and pad them with zeros.

Any advise is be much appreciated.

Comment: why do not you use `rbind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setdiff` to figure out which rows need to be added, create an empty matrix, and `rbind` them together:

```
toAdd <- setdiff(colnames(mat), rownames(mat))
m <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(mat), nrow = length(toAdd), 
            dimnames = list(toAdd, colnames(mat)))
rbind(mat, m)
#   a b c d e
# a 1 0 0 1 0
# e 1 0 0 1 0
# b 0 0 0 0 0
# c 0 0 0 0 0
# d 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

This assumes "mat" is defined as:

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
                .Dim = c(2L, 5L), 
                .Dimnames = list(c("a", "e"), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))
```

Comment: `as.matrix("[<-"(data.frame(mat),setdiff(colnames(mat),rownames(mat)),TRUE,0))` - the most convoluted way I could figure to do this :-)